# Добавить записи в существующую БД SQL из Android приложения

Tags: android, база-данных, sqlite, insert, android-assets

В проект в папку assets подключена база данных с несколькими таблицами. Есть два фрагмента: в первом ListView с названием записи, во втором поля для заполнения и добавления новой записи в предыдущую таблицу. Смотрел примеры для добавления новых записей - показано добавление только с БД, которая создаётся при установке приложения, но с уже подключенной нет. Грешу именно на это. Подскажите, как добавлять записи в таблицу в изначально подключенной БД SQLite. Коды фрагментов ниже:

ListView Fragment:

```
List<String> reportsList;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapterList;
DatabaseHelper mDBHelper;
SQLiteDatabase mDB; 

    @Override
        public void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
        mDBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(getContext());
            try {
                mDB = mDBHelper.getReadableDatabase();
            } catch (SQLException mSQLException) {
                throw mSQLException;
            }
            reportsList = new ArrayList<>();

            //считывание Тайтла репортов из БД
            Cursor cursor = mDB.query("inspector", new String[] {"title"},  "id_inspector = ?", new String[] {String.valueOf(USER)}, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            while(!cursor.isAfterLast()){
                reportsList.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("title")));
                cursor.moveToNext();
            }
            cursor.close();
            //

            adapterList = new ArrayAdapter<>(getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, reportsList);
            list.setAdapter(adapterList);
```

Create Fragment:

```
    DatabaseHelper mDBHelper;
    SQLiteDatabase mDB;

    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "inspector";
    public static final String COLUMN_TITLE = "title";

@Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mDBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(getContext()); //???
        try {
            mDB = mDBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        } catch (SQLException mSQLException) {
            throw mSQLException;
        }
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch(v.getId()){
            case R.id.buttonCreate:

                if(!title.getText().toString().equals("") && !desc.getText().toString().equals("")){
                    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
                    contentValues.put(COLUMN_TITLE, title.getText().toString());

                    mDB.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
                    mDB.close();
                }

                InspectorFragment fragment = new InspectorFragment();
                getActivity()
                        .getSupportFragmentManager()
                        .beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.fragmentBox, fragment)
                        .addToBackStack(null)
                        .commit();
```

Класс DatabaseHelper:

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static String DB_PATH;
    private static String DB_NAME = "info.db";
    private static int DB_VERSION = 1;

    private SQLiteDatabase mDataBase;
    private final Context mContext;

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {

        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
        DB_PATH = context.getApplicationInfo().dataDir + "/databases/";
        this.mContext = context;

        copyDataBase();
        this.getReadableDatabase();
    }

    private boolean checkDataBase() {
        File dbFile = new File(DB_PATH + DB_NAME);
        return dbFile.exists();
    }

    private void copyDataBase() {
        if (checkDataBase()) {
            try {
                copyDBFile();
            } catch (IOException mIOException) {
                throw new Error("ErrorCopyingDataBase");
            }
        }else{

            this.getReadableDatabase();
            this.close();
        }
    }


    private void copyDBFile() throws IOException {


        InputStream mInput = mContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

        OutputStream mOutput = new FileOutputStream(DB_PATH + DB_NAME);


        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = mInput.read(buffer)) > 0)
            mOutput.write(buffer, 0,length);


        mOutput.flush();
        mOutput.close();
        mInput.close();
    }

    public void openDataBase() throws SQLException {

        mDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(DB_PATH + DB_NAME, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void close() {
        if (mDataBase != null)
            mDataBase.close();
        super.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        if(newVersion > oldVersion){
            File dbFile = new File(DB_PATH + DB_NAME);
            if (dbFile.exists())
                dbFile.delete();
            copyDataBase();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Разница лишь в том, что база копируется из `assets`, когда её ещё нет на своём обычном месте - дальше все манипуляции производятся с базой на устройстве, а не в ассетах в любом случае. Так что можете смело делать по примерам для "обычной" базы. Единственное **но** - у вас `onUpgrade()` реализован так, что при повышении версии базы всё записанное при пользовании приложением слетит. Поищите другую реализацию, с реальным апгрейдом, а не перезаписью.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка была в методе `copyDataBase()`. Проверка всегда выдавала false. Решил просто поставив '!' перед `checkDataBase`.